# Array attribute of scope in directive is emptied upon reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My directive looks like this:

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('chart', function () {
      return {
          template: '<div class="chart"></div>',
          restrict: 'E',
          replace: 'true',
          scope: {
              data: '='
          },
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              console.log(scope);
              console.log(scope.data);
          }
      };});
```

and gets passed an array from my controller in the view.

```
<chart data="array"></chart>
```

The console output looks as follows:

```
Scope {...}
$id: "006"
$parent: Child
$root: Scope
...
data: Array[1]
    0: 10300
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
this: Scope
__proto__: Object
```

and

```
[]
```

When the scope object is displayed in the console it has an 'data' attribute with length 1 and the entry '10300', but when scope.data is printed it is just an empty array '[]'.

Why? I am very confused :)

Comment: seems to be working for me http://plnkr.co/edit/nwmFlfR1nl4cStQnsZbT?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the array was initialized in the controller as [] and then filled through a function which was called with $watch. For some reason the two console outputs seem to print different states of the controller. Solution was to call the function once in the controller to initialize the array with values straight away.